How to install R package files that are outside of R studio?
I work in a company that has a very high level of security due to the sensitivity of its work;
those open-sourced R packages are considered unsafe, so everytime I need to install a package, I would have to request it from the IT.
Recently, I wanted to install "tidyverse" onto my R-studio, the IT just sent me a folder that contains all the files related to "tidyverse".
I attached the tidyverse folder here
tidyverse folder
tidyverse subfolder
How do I process these files to make my R studio install the "tidyverse"? I can't just simply type "install.packages("tidyverse") on my R studio becuase it's not going to work since the IT set a security bar on this function.
